# mysql: explain:: index not being used properly

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following sql query: in mysql

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT `daily_price_history`.`id`,
       `daily_price_history`.`symbol`,
       `daily_price_history`.`symbolId_id`,
       `daily_price_history`.`symbolExpectionCount`,
       `daily_price_history`.`url`,
       `daily_price_history`.`volume`,
       `daily_price_history`.`high`,
       `daily_price_history`.`low`,
       `daily_price_history`.`open`,
       `daily_price_history`.`datetime`,
       `daily_price_history`.`datetime_utc`,
       `daily_price_history`.`close`,
       `daily_price_history`.`creation_time`,
       `daily_price_history`.`lot_time`,
       `daily_price_history`.`periodType`
FROM `daily_price_history`
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`datetime` >= 1604718096426
       AND `daily_price_history`.`symbolId_id` IN (26,
                                                   27,
                                                   28,
                                                   29,
                                                   30))
ORDER BY `daily_price_history`.`datetime` ASC
```

I ouput is

```
    id: 1  
    select_type: SIMPLE
    table: daily_price_history
    type: range
    possible_keys: symbolId_id,datetime,idx_datetime_symbol,datetime_symbol_id  
    key: symbolId_id  
    key_len: 4
    ref: (NULL)
    rows: 7940
    Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

I have the following indexes

```
 PRIMARY : id
 symbolId_id : symbolId_id
 datetime : datetime
 idx_datetime_symbol_id : id,datetime,symbolId_id
 datetime_symbol_id : datetime,symbolId_id
```

```
SHOW INDEX FROM daily_price_history
```

result is

```
Table                Non_unique  Key_name              Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
-------------------  ----------  --------------------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
daily_price_history           0  PRIMARY                          1  id           A             11478818    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  symbol_id                        1  symbolId_id  A                17879    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  datetime                         1  datetime     A                 3598    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  idx_datetime_symbol_id           1  datetime     A                34265    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  idx_datetime_symbol_id           2  symbolId_id  A             11478818    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  idx_datetime_symbol_id           3  id           A             11478818    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  datetime_symbol_id               1  datetime     A                34265    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
daily_price_history           1  datetime_symbol_id               2  symbolId_id  A             11478818    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE
```

basically i have a index called `datetime_symbol_id` with datetime and `symbolId_id` but it looks like its not using that index

Comment: How large is your table (number of records) ?

Comment: *I have the following indexes* Unuseful. Provide complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE daily_price_historyжё output.

Comment: The index ```(`symbolId_id`, `datetime`)``` needed for this query.

Comment: edited the question. I have  (`symbolId_id`, `datetime`) this index